# define a button ("Cancel") in React to close the whole react-app but not the Window?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-router

i am trying to define a button ("Cancel") in React to close the whole react-app but not the Window?

<Button onClick={() => window.close()} className={buttonClassses.join(' ')} size="large" variant="contained" color="secondary"> {props.cancel}

What should i do instead of onClick={() => window.close()}?

Comment: What do you mean by "close the whole react-app"? What do you expect the window to contain?

Comment: @Andy i have a react dialog with a html background and by click on Send Button i want to send the data to server and close the dialog. So after this action i should only see the white html page without react dialog.

Answer (score 0):

This will close the tab of the browser but not the whole browser

`window.open("about:blank", "_self"); window.close();`

Hope it  helps

Comment: can i use a function? like this window.open("MyFunction", "_self"); window.close();

Answer (score 0):

Well yes its possible you can call this conditional rendering in which you need to do this on handle state.

in my code you can press **esc** button on which im handling a state which in App.js will render UI on the conditional base

please check the below code and for demo click [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ee7xgo)

> After run demo click **ESC** button which toggle both UI

we know our react app start from index.js or app.js so we can close all the component in App.js and instead of that we can render some UI.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      closeMyApp: true,
    };
  }

  escFunction = (event) => {
    if (event.keyCode === 27) {
      this.setState({ closeMyApp: !this.state.closeMyApp });
    }
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', this.escFunction, false);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('keydown', this.escFunction, false);
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.closeMyApp) {
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>All App Componenet in this section</h1>
          <p>App is runing!</p>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <>
          <h1>App is closed</h1>
          <h3>You can set some UI here like</h3>
        </>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: hi thank you but how would you define a button? by clicking on button, you land on another page?

Comment: Well you can define a button in some common component like header or sidebar.